# Is it possible to get a list of .com.eg domains programmatically?

Tags: dns

I want to create a spider on the Egyptians domains, I was wondering if there is any method I can use to communicate with domain servers to get the list of all domains that end in `.com.eg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse [google's results for "site:.com.eg" search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=site%3A.com.eg&fp=cbc2f75bf9d43a8f).

Here's the code, using python and [xgoogle library](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/):

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
try:
  page = 1
  gs = GoogleSearch("site:.com.eg")
  gs.results_per_page = 100
  results = []
  while page < 10:
      gs.page = page
      results += gs.get_results()
      page += 1
except SearchError, e:
  print "Search failed: %s" % e

for res in results:
    print res.url
```

I got a list of hundreds of ".com.eg" domains with this script.

Answer (score 2):

Some registries offer a way to download the "zone file" which is a list of all domains registered with the registry. I looked on http://www.nic.eg but I can't read Arabic and they didn't offer an English translation of most pages.

You will be looking for something like VeriSign's [TLD Zone Access Program](http://www.verisign.com/domain-name-services/domain-information-center/tld-zone-access/index.html).

Alexa's [Top Sites](http://www.alexa.com/topsites) page offers a download of the top 1 million domain names globally. There are just 43 names from .com.eg in that list though, here they are:

> google.com.eg
>   vodafone.com.eg
>   telecomegypt.com.eg
>   yellowpages.com.eg
>   efa.com.eg
>   etisalat.com.eg
>   nbe.com.eg
>   carrefour.com.eg
>   link.com.eg
>   edita.com.eg
>   gom.com.eg
>   vodafonelive.com.eg
>   travian.com.eg
>   nilesat.com.eg
>   toyotaegypt.com.eg
>   faisalbank.com.eg
>   oriflame.com.eg
>   nsgb.com.eg
>   skoool.com.eg
>   betterhome.com.eg
>   espace.com.eg
>   mcsd.com.eg
>   banquemisr.com.eg
>   mobileshop.com.eg
>   st.com.eg
>   egyptinmypocket.com.eg
>   hyperone.com.eg
>   resala.com.eg
>   arabbank.com.eg
>   nestle.com.eg
>   eaec.com.eg
>   elman.com.eg
>   nas.com.eg
>   nissan.com.eg
>   asset.com.eg
>   tech.com.eg
>   selaheltelmeez.com.eg
>   mh.com.eg
>   cookdoor.com.eg
>   siemens.com.eg
>   bmisr-payment.com.eg
>   citystars.com.eg
>   global-id.com.eg

Comment: http://www.egregistry.eg/index-e.php is the english version of the site but i didnt find any zone files there

Answer (score 1):

No, but it's possible to get all of the IP address ranges in Egypt.

[this might help](http://www.find-ip-address.org/ip-country/).

Comment: well this is nice, i can try to resolve this ips to domain names. and since hte hosting of .com.eg domains required to be in egypt i can get the list of domains that ends in .com.eg

Comment: If you do that, you might want to rate-limit the requests to the DNS server; if you just request reverse-lookup all of those IPs, doing them as quickly as possible may kill the DNS server.

Answer (score -1):

No باشا, you can't do that.

No server will give you this information.